# IE ignores styles for dynamically loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I've seen a couple similar questions here with no real answers. Hopefully someone notices this...

IE 8 and below are refusing to apply styles from the css stylesheet defined in the header when they are loaded in a document.ready jquery call.

Paranoid client wants NOBODY to see code or the dev site so I'll have to give a short example.
The client wants the site to render only the relevant portion of HTML on a nearly exclusively "ajaxed" site. So, the site is like a grid. If you load the homepage you get this:

```
<div id="content">
    <section id="home">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Hi There!</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Then onload I use jquery to render the surrounding pages...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').append('<section id="about"><h1>About Us</h1></section>');
});
```

IE can handle this much, but when it comes to respecting my carefully plotted css, it just ignores the styles and laughs at me.

The site is entirely positioned with absolute positioning, tons of z-indexing and a horrendous amount of jquery animation. The kind of thing you do not want to have recreate in some extra stupid way for some inferior yet dominantly used browser. Dear god please tell me someone has figured out some way to get IE to respect defined styles on elements created after load.

Have ye any ideas?

- I know chunks of real code are preferred but this is succinct and tells you enough without having a full blown audit. Even if the only defined style is #about{ display:none; } it is ignored. The about section is written as requested but it is display block by default.
- I also know this is not technically ajaxing, but I'm using technical jargon to attempt to clarify the order of page loading in as much as it is not standard loaded html.

**THE SOLUTION**

```
$('#content').append($('<section>').attr('id', 'about').html('<h1>About Us</h1><p>some text</p>'));
```

Properly applies the element as well as the css for this and all children. Not sure why nested elements are read properly by IE without having to be declared the same way, but I am definitely grateful. Thanks jfriend00 and everyone else who helped.

Comment: Are you allowed to post some of the offending css?  That would mean we could fire up the sample in our own browsers.  Even better would be to post a sample on http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can play around with it ourselves.

Comment: IE works perfectly fine with styles and classes.  I use it all the time with dynamically added elements.  For us to help, you have to give us a specific example that doesn't work in IE and we can help you find what's wrong.  You don't have to rewrite your code or HTML or CSS.  You probably just have some silly parsing error in HTML or CSS.  If you create a jsFiddle that illustrates the problem, we can help you fix it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eDqca/1/

I have it stripped to almost nothing. There are no errors or warnings. The jsfiddle recretes as mentioned in this posting. jsfiddle is getting an error onload, but is still demonstrating the problem

Comment: Also, it is not related to html5 elements, so much as I can tell. I tried it on standard divs with just text inside and it still produced the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that this line of code does not generate the desired set of HTML objects in IE7/IE8:

```
$('#content').append('<section id="about"><h1>About Us</h1></section>');
```

If you look in the IE DOM inspector, you don't see the desired tags nested appropriately so the DOM is messed up and thus the style rules don't work appropriately.  The issue is how things are getting inserted into the DOM by jQuery.  I think it's a jQuery interaction problem with IE more than anything else.

Without stepping through the code in detail on IE, I can't say whether it's actually a jQuery issue or an IE issue or just one of those weired combo bugs.  Obviously, IE has earned the right of first blame for it's previous transgressions, but it's probably better to just avoid this bug by using some more straightforward code.

Breaking down the code a bit, this code works for me in IE7:  Here, we create a single tag, add some innerHTML to it and then insert that root tag using append() rather than give HTML to append.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var section = $("<section>");
    section.attr("id", "about");
    section.html('<h1>About Us</h1>');
    $('#content').append(section);
});
```

You can see the revised code work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vEST8/

I don't know why IE has a problem with appending an whole HTML string directly via jQuery, but I have seen this problem before.

Comment: Precisely so. I tested your method and it works. Hopefully it is this basic for everything. By the way, it should append "section" and not "div" in case anyone tries to copy / paste to test it.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this code in IE7.  I can't get IE7 to dynamically create the right objects when there are <section> tags in the HTML.

Comment: If it helps to know at all, I am having success in IE7 and 8 with this condensed version of your same suggestion:

$('#content').append($('<section>').attr('id', 'about').html('<h1>some text</h1><p>some more text</p>'));  

It is properly rendering the element as well as applying styles to all children. Thanks

Comment: this fixed things for me.  surprised more people aren't arriving on this page.  must be a combination of factors that cause this?

Answer (score 1):

To be safe, use jQuery to apply said classes after the append:

```
$('#content').append('<section id="about"><h1>About Us</h1></section>');
$("#about").addClass("foo");
```

Comment: I was kind of afraid of that since there are about 2,000 elements added and doing as mentioned here applies the class properly, and it might even respect the definition of the said class. But it utterly ignores the request for all children. So $('#about').addClass('hidden'); hides the about section but the h1 inside is still display block and showing proudly, even though the parent is supposedly hidden.

Comment: That sucks. I supposed you could re-apply *all* styles to *all* appended elements - there must be a better way.