# IE7: .remove() does not work - element (byID) does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code below DOES NOT work in IE7, but works perfectly in all other browsers tested.

The element `'#requestFormContainer'` comes into existence after the `.ajax` request below.

In fact, `$('#requestFormContainer').length` equals 1 in all browsers tested, but equals 0 in IE7. So it's just not there. No errors in IE's debug tool or Firebug. I'm out of ideas.

```
function ShowEventForm(erid) {
    $.ajax ({'url': '<?php echo $GLOBALS['SERVER_NAME_HTTP']; ?>ajax/ajax.showrequestform.php',
    'data': {'task':'ShowRequestInfo','erid':erid},
    'dataType':'html', 'type': 'POST',
    'success': function (data) { 
        $('#eventListContainer').hide();
        $('#clientContentPanel').append(data);
        $('#backToEventList').click(function() {
            $('#requestFormContainer').remove();
            $('#eventListContainer').show();
        });
    } 
    });
}
```

Updates - No solution with following changes:

I've changed

`$('#clientContentPanel').append(data)` TO `$(data).appendTo('#clientContentPanel')`

and

Removed and relocated some js code from the offending element:

`<div id="requestFormContainer">`

Comment: How about a jsfiddle? --- maybe just replicate your 'success' bit.

Comment: @jim bailie use .detach() instead .remove()

Comment: @Sol - I should have mentioned that I did try detach() before posting and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding $('#requestFormContainer') to the dom?

You can look into jQuery .live which is the common answer to this problem.

Otherwise, you can re-examine how $('#requestFormContainer') is being added to the dom...

```
var elem = $('<div>');
elem.html('this is the inner contents of the new element');
elem.attr('id', 'requestFormContainer');
body.append(elem);
```

will also add the element in IE in a usable way...

as opposed to the logical way:

```
$('body').append('<div id="requestFormContainer"><p>some html</p></div>');
```

which IE can have problems dealing with.

I would look into live() first though.
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Also I don't think this needs to be in your ajax response (I updated it to live version)...

```
 $('#backToEventList').live('click', function() {
      $('#requestFormContainer').remove();
      $('#eventListContainer').show();
 });
```

Since it is a listener on a non-existent object it is harmless if it is outside the ajax request and .live will still see it as an object when it is added in the response.

Comment: The problem element is `<div id="requestFormContainer">` and is introduced in the ajax response (data) and is appended to it's parent, `<div id="clientContentPanel">`. I see your point about .live(), but the click event that triggers the remove() is...live already. And I am unable to introduce the element any other way because there's a lot of stuff in it and it has to sit where it is.

Comment: It occurred to me that your listener was defined in your response. I think that should be moved outside the ajax request. I updated my answer

Comment: also, that weird way of adding the element was necessary for me on an all ajax project. I had to return a json object with the parent element separate from the expected html so I could build an element as defined above. I think it is because IE will interpret it as a string only. This is probably happening to you if requestFormContainer is not accepting any css styles after being written in.

Comment: Kai - Thanks for your thoughts on this. I did take the listener out of the .ajax call and made it .live() to no avail. I do think you're onto something with regard to how IE treats an append(). I'm starting to think that I'm going to have to figure out a new way to situate things.

Comment: No problem. My response was based on this question I asked fairly recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590537/ie-ignores-styles-for-dynamically-loaded-content