# IE8 Unable to print dynamic Elements

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing

Anyone have any idea why dynamic elements that are cloned from one part of a page to another would not print in IE8?

Example:

```
// Content div for element to be cloned to
<div class="content"></div>

// Element to be cloned to .content
<p>Some Text</p>

// Final result after cloning
<div class="content"><p>Some Text</p></div>
```

I am using jQuery clone() method to clone elements.

Thanks in advance for your help!

UPDATE:

I was actually missing a class in the logic of the code. It seems that I was looking for a class that wasn't being included in IE, thus the element that was being printed had a display:none. In this case the logic was failing to meet expectations, and we found a solution for the problem.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Splitting up the code a bit and creating the same element again, will fix the problem for cloning elements:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content"></div>
<p class="cloneMe">Some Text</p>​
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var p = $("<p class='cloneMe'>");
    p.html( $('p.cloneMe').html() );
    //p.clone().appendTo('.content'); // clone() no longer necessary
    p.appendTo('.content');
});​
```

**Live Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/4b9z3/3/

**More about this**: [IE ignores styles for dynamically loaded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590537/ie-ignores-styles-for-dynamically-loaded-content/7590830#7590830)