# JQuery AJAX and php gallery slide show

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, slideshow

I create a gallery with Jquery and it worked fine, later on I decided to get the file from directory and not from   tag.

I used AJAX and PHP, I get the images into the gallery div but the css class not influence the the gallery to make it work.

**html**

```
        <div id="gallery-holder">
    <!--            <img src="images/mainGallery/main-galery1.jpg" class="active"  >
                    <img src="images/mainGallery/main-galery2.jpg" >
                    <img src="images/mainGallery/main-galery3.jpg" >
    -->
                </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url: 'mainGallery.php',                                 
                success: function(data){
                 $('#gallery-holder').html(data);

                  }
             }).error(function(){
                alert('an alert occored');
                }).success(function(){
            //  alert('success');
                }).complete(function(){
            //  alert('complete');
                });     


    slideSwitch();

    });

    function slideSwitch() {

        var $gallery = $('#gallery-holder'),

            $active  = $gallery.find('img:visible'),

            $next    = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $gallery.find('img').first();



        setTimeout(function() {

            $active.fadeOut('slow');

            $next.fadeIn('slow', slideSwitch);

        }, 2000);

    };
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php
        $i=0;
     foreach(glob('./images/mainGallery/*.*' ) as $filename){
        if ($i==0){
            echo '<img src="'.$filename.'" class="active">';
        }
        else echo '<img src="'.$filename.'">';
        $i++;
     }

    ?>
```

It's look like the HTML is not recognize the Active class form the AJAX.
No errors in the console.

please help...

thanks,
Cfir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your function call inside the success callback, otherwise it will run before the elements have been added:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mainGallery.php',                                 
        success: function(data){
            $('#gallery-holder').html(data);
            slideSwitch(); //Initialize slider after elements are loaded into the DOM
        }
    );   
});
```

Comment: And close the `img` tags in your PHP.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to add thumbnails to my gallery?

Answer (score 0):

Inferring from this: [IE ignores styles for dynamically loaded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590537/ie-ignores-styles-for-dynamically-loaded-content),  I'd suggest you try and return something like `<img src="images/mainGallery/main-galery1.jpg" id="displayimg">` from your PHP, and then do:

```
$('#gallery-holder').html(data);
$('#displayimg').addClass("active");
```

Try it.