# ie8 not rendering css in ajax call

Tags: html, css, ajax, internet-explorer-8

What I'm doing is creating buttons to download a web app. The issue I'm having is specifically to IE8. What I have is a button with a gradient, hover states, an image, and a few other attributes. When testing in FF, Chrome, Safari, and IE 9+ the Ajax call for the button works as expected. In IE8 however no styles seem to be applying. I have a specific ajax call depending on browser to load the correct button to download the correct web app. For IE I was having issues loading external stylesheets so I decided to just put the styles in the

```
<head><styles>...</styles></head>
```

for IE specifically which worked for IE 9+. The styles also work in IE8 when not being used in Ajax call so that's not the issue. So I'm not sure the best course of action to make IE8 render the CSS that's in the `<head>` of the call.

I'm new to using Ajax calls as a heads up.

Comment: IE will render the response as text. You have to actually create the dom objects and insert them.Are you using jquery by chance?

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago. Here's the jquery fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590537/ie-ignores-styles-for-dynamically-loaded-content

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Yes, I'm using jQuery 1.4.2 which is controlling all the backend work.

Comment: That article helped a ton was able to get the example working. Just have to adhere it to the in place code and will be all set.