# IE7 and IE8 ignoring CSS with dynamic content in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using ajax to populate a navigation menu but I am having difficulty in rendering the CSS in an external stylesheet.  It is definitely something to do with the way jQuery is being used to dynamically create the DOM elements since I can reproduce it when removing the ajax call.  Please see the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMHV4/).  This is my jQuery to create the HTML:

```
var menuItem = $("<a>").attr('href', field.link).html(field.name);
var menuSpan = $('<span></span>').append(menuItem);

var menuLi = $('<li></li>').append(menuSpan);
$('.nav > div > div > ul').append(menuLi);
```

As you can see my list item has a background colour and is floated in the decent browsers but not IE7 or IE8.

I think it is a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590537/ie-ignores-styles-for-dynamically-loaded-content) but I am really struggling to see what the problem is since the markup appears to be fine when I inspect in IE

This code is working on a production site where the content is not dynamically created so I am stumped!  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var menuItem = document.createElement("a");
menuItem.innerText=field.name;
menuItem.setAttribute('href', field.link);

var menuSpan = document.createElement("span");
menuSpan.appendChild(menuItem)


var menuLi = document.createElement("li");
menuLi.appendChild(menuSpan)

   $(menuLi).appendTo('.nav ul');
```